# MYSQL echo show me decimal and non decimal

Tags: php, mysql

I take data from a mysql databae. 2 from 3 echos show me a dot behind the number. For example:
 32500.00€
the third doesnt show me that. Jusdt: 32500.
In the best case i want this format in the echo: 32.500.00€

Here is my code:

```
$sum_success_sql = "select SUM(kredithhe) as sum from wp_participants_database where angenommen = 'Ja' And standort = '" . $location['standort'] . "'";
$sum_success_res = runQuery($sum_success_sql, $pdo);

$sum_fail_sql = "select SUM(kredithhe) as sum from wp_participants_database where angenommen = 'Nein' And standort = '" . $location['standort'] . "'";
$sum_fail_res = runQuery($sum_fail_sql, $pdo);

$count_fail_sql = "select count(*) as num from wp_participants_database where angenommen = 'Nein' And standort = '" . $location['standort'] . "'";
$count_fail_res = runQuery($count_fail_sql, $pdo);

$count_success_sql = "select count(*) as num from wp_participants_database where angenommen = 'Ja' And standort = '" . $location['standort'] . "'";
$count_success_res = runQuery($count_success_sql, $pdo);

$temp = array();

$temp['location'] = $location['standort'];
$temp['sum_fail'] = $sum_fail_res['sum'];
$temp['sum_success'] = $sum_success_res['sum'];
$temp['num_fail'] = $count_fail_res['num'];
$temp['num_success'] = $count_success_res['num'];
$temp['num_total'] = $count_success_res['num'] + $count_fail_res['num'];
$temp['sum_total'] = $sum_fail_res['sum'] + $sum_success_res['sum'];
```

The output is the following:

```
<td><?php echo utf8_encode($res['location']) ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['num_total'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['num_success'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['num_fail'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['sum_total'] ?>€</td>
<td><?php echo $res['sum_fail'] ?>€</td>
<td><?php echo $res['sum_success'] ?>€</td>
```

and this is the result:

```
Location    NR  NR  NR 39500€   28000.00€   11500.00€
```

Answer (score 2):

Use number_format() function.

Example:

```
$number = 1000;
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

> output: 1,000.00

Answer (score 2):

You can use php number formatting.

**Example:**

```
echo number_format($res['sum_total'], 2, ',', '.')."€";
```

> 5000,00€

**Example:**

```
echo "€".number_format($res['sum_total'], 2, ',', '.');
```

> €5000,00

**Example:**

```
echo number_format($res['sum_total'], 2, ',', '.');
```

> 5000,00

More information about PHP number format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: i need this: 100.450,00